# Update selectInput on change of another selectInput

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I need to change the value of one `selectInput`, with its own input id, whenever the value of another `selectInput`, with a different input id changes.

In javascript this would be `onchage`, but I can't figure out how to interface the two.

*jQuery*, or *R* code is OK.

*EDIT:* Got it to work with this code:

```
observe({ 
    choices <- input$product
    updateSelectInput(session, "productexperiance", 
                        choices=c("NA", paste(ProductList())), selected="NA")
  })
```

Still I don't understand why it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `observe` and `updateSelectInput`. Assume one selectInput called col and another called value:

```
observe({
    choices <- values[input$col]
    updateSelectInput(session, "value", choices=choices)
})
```

The first line of the observer was just standing in for whatever logic you want to use to decide what the choices are for the second `selectInput`. values was just a hypothetical vector or list that contains some data.

The important thing is that you access the value of the first `selectInput` inside the observer; this will cause the observer to re-execute whenever that value changes.

Comment: Joe, I don't quite understand; values is not a function or an input.

Also, I don't want to change input1 to = input2;
I want to make input2 revert to NA whenever there is a change in input1

Comment: Actually, I got it to work using an observer! 

But I still don't understand _why_ it work? 

EDIT: Moved code to my own post

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, the first line of the observer was just standing in for whatever logic you want to use to decide what the choices are for the second selectInput. `values` was just a hypothetical vector or list that contains some data. The important thing is that you access the value of the first selectInput inside the observer; this will cause the observer to re-execute whenever that value changes.

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery (you have to have the JQuery script loaded to use it)

```
$('#select1').change(function(){ 
    $('#select2').val('1');
});
```

You'll have to play with it a bit... (not tested)

The # denotes an element by it's ID - The actual ID can be anything (besides select1 or select2)

in my example when select1 is changed select2 will then also be changed.

the '1' in the val() should correspond to an actual value that is available through the other list.